# list<rectangle[]> array grouping

Tags: c#

I have an array of rectangle elements. each element in the array can be able to represent several diffrent rectangles in it. i would want to find out how can i group similar list items and show their count. e.g  the list contains 10 rectangle arrays. of the 10 there are 4 elements which are similar (i.e  4 rectangle elements with the same number, size, orientation of the rectangles in it) for the example i would love  to have an end result which shows a list of 7 alements and the count eg. the 6 single elements and the 7th elements showing a count of 4. c# or vb.net

Answer (score 2):

If you can override `Equals` on your rectangle to determine when you consider two rectangles equal, you could do the following Linq query.

```
        List<Rectangle[]> rectangleArr;
        var query = (from r in rectangleArr.Cast<Rectangle>()
                     group r by r into gr
                     select new { Count = gr.Count(), Value = gr.Key });
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, Count: {1}", item.Value, item.Count);
        }
```

If you don't want an anonymous type you could create a class:

```
class RectangleGroup
{
    public Rectangle Value { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

then select like this:

```
select new RectangleGroup() { Count = gr.Count(), Value = gr.Key }
```

Comment: If the `Rectangle` was a `struct` then you wouldn't need to override `Equals`.

Comment: it looks there might be a bit of mis understanding. here is my scenario....  List<Rectangle[]> allsolution = new List<Rectangle[]>(); this is a list of rectangle arrays. now each array can hev as many rectangles inside it...all i want is to group similar rectangle arrays and state how many times they appear...your solution is giving me a check within the rectangle array and then grouping them there.

Comment: // variable to hold final solution

list<rectangle[]> allsheetsgrouped = new list<rectangle[]>;

//get sheet solution

rectangle[x] sheet = new rectangle[x];

sheet.add(rectangles); //adds rectangles to sheet.

//after a sheet is complete it adds it to the final solution variable.

allsheetsgrouped.add(sheet);

 // when my packing algorithim completes. i have a final list with all the sheets. all i want is to group similar sheets. i.e. u can not just use length or count to group them since sheets can have same number of rectangles but wth diffrent sizes.

Comment: I was not using length or count to group them, it is determining equal rectangles by value. You seem to have requirements that need a more complex comparison, you need to make a formal definition for 'Similar Rectangles'

Comment: ts a board cutting solution lets say a sheet can only be 10m * 10m. then within that sheet i will try to put in board cuts that fit in perfectly or near perfect. if my final solution has lets say 4 sheets required. 1st sheet containing 100 * 1m*1m cuts, 2nd has the same, third has only 2 5m * 10m cuts, and lastly has only 1 9m * 9m cut.....in this case 1st and 2nd sheet contain similar contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tuple:

```
List<Rectangle> l = new List<Rectangle>();
l.Add(new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4));
l.Add(new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4));
l.Add(new Rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40));

var grouped = l
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(group => new Tuple<Rectangle, int>(group.Key, group.Count()));

foreach (var t in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There are {0} rectangles like {1}.", t.Item2, t.Item1);
}
```

Comment: i am a bit lost here...say i have my list called rects how do i implement it with the above code

Comment: it looks there might be a bit of mis understanding. here is my scenario....  List<Rectangle[]> allsolution = new List<Rectangle[]>(); this is a list of rectangle arrays. now each array can hev as many rectangles inside it...all i want is to group similar rectangle arrays and state how many times they appear...your solution is giving me a check within the rectangle array and then grouping them there.

Comment: define 'similar rectangle arrays'

Comment: its a board cutting solution lets say a sheet can only be 10m * 10m. then within that sheet i will try to put in board cuts that fit in perfectly or near perfect. if my final solution has lets say 4 sheets required. 1st sheet containing 100 * 1m*1m cuts, 2nd has the same, third has only 2 5m * 10m cuts, and lastly has only 1 9m * 9m cut.....in this case 1st and 2nd sheet contain similar contents.

Comment: // variable to hold final solution

list<rectangle[]> allsheetsgrouped = new list<rectangle[]>;

//get sheet solution

rectangle[x] sheet = new rectangle[x];

sheet.add(rectangles); //adds rectangles to sheet.

//after a sheet is complete it adds it to the final solution variable.

allsheetsgrouped.add(sheet);

 // when my packing algorithim completes. i have a final list with all the sheets. all i want is to group similar sheets. i.e. u can not just use length or count to group them since sheets can have same number of rectangles but wth diffrent sizes.